# a list input method

Tags: java, list, input, nullpointerexception

I'm new to list and I have a problem with the method below:
the problem is: `java.lang.NullPointerException`

Code:

```
public static List<Integer> input(List<Integer> l)
{
        Node<Integer> pos=l.getFirst();
        System.out.println("Enter num (!=999)");
        int x = reader.nextInt();
        l.insert(null, x);
        while(x!=999)
        {
                System.out.println("Enter num (!=999)");
                l.insert(pos, x);
                pos = pos.getNext();
        }

        return l;
}
```

**Silly me I forgot the input message inside the while...**

Comment: What line does the error message occur on?

Comment: in    pos = pos.getNext();

Comment: You need to post some more code.  Where have you initialized `reader`?

Comment: I don't think that the problem is with the input. 
I've already written "static Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);"

Comment: Can you provide the source of `Node<T>` and `List<T>` class, or a link to the library you are using?

Comment: There is not such method as `getFirst` in `List` interface. What implementation are you using?

Comment: list: http://pastebin.com/HvEbT8X6

Comment: node: http://pastebin.com/cQG0i5u5

Comment: here: 
'    public Node<T> getFirst()
    {  
                return(this.first);
    }      
   '

Comment: Never Ever use pre-defined class names as your own defined classes.

Comment: what do you mean?  @RohitJain

Comment: List is a pre-defined interface. And you used it to create your own. That confused us, as you didn't gave your own implementation. Further, that will create problems, when you use the pre-defined classes in your code.

Comment: So how can I get an original class of list?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23513/discussion-between-nitzan-batat-and-rohit-jain)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you initialized `l` as an empty list, then the call to

```
Node<Integer> pos=l.getFirst();
```

would return `null`.  Then later, you call `pos.getNext();` on a `null` instance, hence the `NullPointerException`.  One way to fix this would be to handle the possibility of the empty list inside your `while` loop, like this:

```
while (x != 999)
{
    System.out.println("Enter num (!=999)");
    l.insert(pos, x);
    if (pos == null)
        pos = l.getFirst();
    else
        pos = pos.getNext();
}
```

When you run this, you'll see the second problem in your code, which you should be able to resolve.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Two possibilities:

1. your "`pos`" reference is `null` (you can check for that)
2. the "`pos`" object contains a NULL object, which the compiler then tries to autobox to a primitive type somewhere (the `Node` thing is declared as `Integer` object type)

SO: check for `null` before trying to access "`pos`", AND use "`Integer`" object when declaring stuff as such.